# How setVisibility gone all other position when click on another position in recylerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have stuck by a logic and unable to achieve the desired result. I have a recycler view which has another horizontal child recycler view. I am able to expand collapse the view on click of the item. I want that when I clicked on one element only current position should expand all the other position got collapse. I tried a lot of logic but no one is worked for me.

My recycler view adapter code is :

```
public class NewAdpater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewAdpater.ViewHolder> implements Response.ErrorListener {
    Context context;
    boolean flag=true;
    private List<FetchDocument> docDatalist;
    int customerSerial;
    private int expandedPosition = -1;

    private int vinappserial;
    ImageFetchResponse response;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps;
    SendHoldertdata sendHoldertdata;
    UtilityOfActivity utilityOfActivity;
    List<ImageFetchResponseDocumentList> list = new ArrayList<>();


    public NewAdpater(List<FetchDocument> docDatalist, Context context, String vinappserial, SendHoldertdata sendHoldertdata) {

        this.docDatalist = docDatalist;
        this.context = context;
        this.sendHoldertdata = sendHoldertdata;
        utilityOfActivity = new UtilityOfActivity((Activity) context);
        this.vinappserial = Integer.valueOf(vinappserial);
        UserDetail userDetail = new Gson().fromJson(PrefrenceFile.getInstance().getString(Constant.PREF_KEY_USER_DATA), UserDetail.class);
        customerSerial = userDetail.getLoginResponse().getCustInfo().getCustSerialNo();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.doc_send_item_list, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.recyclerViewImages.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.doc_type.setText(docDatalist.get(position).getDocTypeDesc());

        // expandedPosition=holder.getAdapterPosition();

        holder.myDocumentListCollapse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                boolean shouldExpand = holder.recyclerViewImages.getVisibility() == View.GONE;
                if (shouldExpand) {
                    holder.recyclerViewImages.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    holder.iconexpandCollapse.setImageResource(R.mipmap.expand_4);
                    imagerequestserver(docDatalist.get(position), vinappserial, holder);
                    //   DocumentImageFetchResponseListner setData= new DocumentImageFetchResponseListner(holder);

                } else {

                    holder.recyclerViewImages.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.iconexpandCollapse.setImageResource(R.mipmap.expand);
                }



            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return docDatalist.size();
    }

    public interface SendHoldertdata {
        void setdata(ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArrayList, int count);
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView doc_type;
        LinearLayout myDocumentListCollapse;
        RelativeLayout layoutAddDoc;
        ImageView iconexpandCollapse;
        RecyclerView recyclerViewImages;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            doc_type = itemView.findViewById(R.id.doc_type);
            myDocumentListCollapse = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myDocumentListCollapse);
            layoutAddDoc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layoutAddDoc);
            iconexpandCollapse = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iconexpandCollapse);
            recyclerViewImages = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewImages);
            recyclerViewImages.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

    public void imagerequestserver(FetchDocument fetchDocument, int vinappserial, ViewHolder holder) {

        ImageFetchRequest imageFetchRequest = new ImageFetchRequest();
        imageFetchRequest.setCustSerial(customerSerial);
        imageFetchRequest.setDocGroup(fetchDocument.getDocTypeCode());
        imageFetchRequest.setVehSerial(String.valueOf(vinappserial));
        imageFetchRequest.setDocSerial("0");
        String url = Constant.API_MAIN + Constant.API_DOCUMENT_IMAGEFETCH;
        AbstractVolleyRequest jsonObjectrequest = new
                AbstractVolleyRequest(url, this, new DocumentImageFetchResponseListner(fetchDocument, vinappserial, holder), imageFetchRequest, Request.Method.POST);
        jsonObjectrequest.setTag("DocumentImageFetchRequest");
        Log.v("DocumentFetchRequest", "DocumentImageFetchRequest" + jsonObjectrequest);
        VolleyRequestQue.getmInstance(context.getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectrequest);

    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        if (context != null) {
            utilityOfActivity.progresDissmiss();
        }
        utilityOfActivity.toast(context.getString(R.string.connectivity_server_error));
    }

    public class DocumentImageFetchResponseListner extends MyListner<ImageFetchResponse> implements MailDocumentListAdapter.ISelectedImageMail {
        FetchDocument fetchDocument;
        String vinappserial;
        public ViewHolder holder;


        public DocumentImageFetchResponseListner(FetchDocument fetchDocument, int vinappserial, ViewHolder holder) {
            super(ImageFetchResponse.class);
            this.vinappserial = String.valueOf(vinappserial);
            this.fetchDocument = fetchDocument;
            this.holder = holder;
            utilityOfActivity.progressDialogShow(context.getString(R.string.please_wait));
        }


        @Override
        public void onResponse(MyResponse instaResponse) {
            utilityOfActivity.progresDissmiss();
            if (instaResponse != null) {
                if (instaResponse instanceof ImageFetchResponse) {
                    response = (ImageFetchResponse) instaResponse;
                    if (response.getResult().getResultStatus().contains("SUCCESS")) {
                        list = response.getDocumentList();

                        // list.addAll(newList);
                        Log.d("", "");
                        if (list.size() > 0) {
                            setData();

                        }

                    } else {
                        utilityOfActivity.toast(context.getString(R.string.connectivity_server_error));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void setData() {
            MailDocumentListAdapter recyclerViewNewAdpater = new MailDocumentListAdapter(context, list, this);
            holder.recyclerViewImages.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 3));
            recyclerViewNewAdpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
            holder.recyclerViewImages.setAdapter(recyclerViewNewAdpater);
        }

        @Override
        public void sendBitMap(ArrayList<Bitmap> itemSelectedArrayList,int count) {
            bitmaps = itemSelectedArrayList;
            sendHoldertdata.setdata(bitmaps,count);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my DialogFragment where I am setting Adapter:

```
public class DialogMailDocument extends DialogFragment implements NewAdpater.SendHoldertdata {
    TextView txtCount;
    int count=0;
    ImageView documentCross;
    RecyclerView recyclerViewDocument;
    UtilityOfActivity utilityOfActivity;
    AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity;
    NewAdpater mainAdapter;
    private int expandedPosition = -1;
    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> sendImageBitmap = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ImageFetchResponseDocumentList> imageFetchResponseDocumentLists;
    List<FetchDocument> fetchDocuments;
    String vinappSerail;
    MailDocumentListAdapter.ISelectedImageMail selectedImageMail;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.fullscreen_dialog);
    }

    private void init(View view) {
        txtCount = view.findViewById(R.id.txtCount);
       // selectAll = view.findViewById(R.id.selectAll);
        recyclerViewDocument = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewDocument);
        TextView tvSendDoc = view.findViewById(R.id.tvSendDoc);
         documentCross = view.findViewById(R.id.documentCross);
        documentCross.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
        });
        tvSendDoc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (sendImageBitmap != null) {
                    email(getActivity(), "xyz@gmail.com", "hello", sendImageBitmap);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Nothing is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        setDocumentRecyclerView();

    }

    public DialogMailDocument newInstance(MailDocumentListAdapter.ISelectedImageMail iSelectedImageMail) {
        DialogMailDocument fragment = new DialogMailDocument();
        this.selectedImageMail = iSelectedImageMail;
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        utilityOfActivity = new UtilityOfActivity(activity);
        appCompatActivity = (AppCompatActivity) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_mail_document, container, false);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            imageFetchResponseDocumentLists = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("documentList");
            fetchDocuments = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("documentListHead");
            vinappSerail = bundle.getString("vinappSerail");
        }

        init(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void setDocumentRecyclerView() {
        mainAdapter = new NewAdpater(fetchDocuments, getActivity(), vinappSerail, this,expandedPosition);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerViewDocument.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerViewDocument.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
//
//        GridLayoutManager manager =
//                new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3);
//        recyclerViewDocument.setLayoutManager(manager);
//        mainAdapter.setLayoutManager(manager);
//        adapter.shouldShowHeadersForEmptySections(hideEmpty);
//        adapter.shouldShowFooters(showFooters);
        recyclerViewDocument.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
        mainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }

    public void email(Context context, String emailTo, String emailText, ArrayList<Bitmap> filePaths) {
        //need to "send multiple" to get more than one attachment
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        emailIntent.setType("image/*");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[]{emailTo});
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailText);
        //has to be an ArrayList
        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        //convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's
        for (Bitmap file : filePaths) {
            Uri u = getImageUri(getActivity(), file);
            uris.add(u);
        }

        emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
    }


    @Override
    public void setdata(ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArrayList,int count) {
        sendImageBitmap = bitmapArrayList;
        this.count=count;
        txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count)+" selected");

    }

    @Override
    public void setExpandedPosition(int expandedPosition) {
        DialogMailDocument.this.expandedPosition = expandedPosition;
        mainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: the second recyclerView is first's child ?

Comment: Thanks, @Umair Yes you got it right.

Comment: Why not use a `scrollview` instead of a `recycler view` ?

Comment: @Champondroid I once faced the similar issue and had to use a library to make it work by default recyclerview doesn't provide this functionality. if you want i can give you the link of that library.

Comment: If I will go to the library I have to write a lot of code again. I have simply one issue. I have no choice rather than solve it.

Comment: @Champandorid ok let me post some code from that library to give you the idea how I did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a boolean "isShow" in model class and set it as false by default for all items of your recyclerview.

then....

```
if (list.get(position).isShow()) {
    // show item....
} else {
    // hide item....
}
```

Simplest way to iterate one more for loop inside onBindViewHolder method just as below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
   if (i == position) {
       if (list.get(position).isShow()) {
           list.get(position).setShow(false);
       } else {
           list.get(position).setShow(true);
       }
   } else {
       list.get(i).setShow(false);
   }
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Ask me for more queries.

Thanks.

Comment: Sure. I would like to help. Thanks.

Comment: Where could I put the loop?

Comment: As I told you, just add for loop inside onBindViewHolder method of recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a boolean variable (default false) in the model class, and if you open a view on single click, set the flag as true for that position and the remaining would be false. According this firstly check the position item flag and show or gone according it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting it on the adapter, hold the expanded child `position` on the `activity` (or `fragment`) and call the `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

```
private int expandedPosition = -1; //just set -1 for default

public NewAdpater(List<FetchDocument> docDatalist, Context context, String vinappserial, SendHoldertdata sendHoldertdata, int expandedPosition) {

    this.docDatalist = docDatalist;
    this.context = context;
    this.sendHoldertdata = sendHoldertdata;
    utilityOfActivity = new UtilityOfActivity((Activity) context);
    this.vinappserial = Integer.valueOf(vinappserial);
    UserDetail userDetail = new Gson().fromJson(PrefrenceFile.getInstance().getString(Constant.PREF_KEY_USER_DATA), UserDetail.class);
    customerSerial = userDetail.getLoginResponse().getCustInfo().getCustSerialNo();
    this.expandedPosition = expandedPosition;
}

...more codes...

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.recyclerViewImages.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.doc_type.setText(docDatalist.get(position).getDocTypeDesc());

    if (expandedPosition == position) {
       holder.recyclerViewImages.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       holder.iconexpandCollapse.setImageResource(R.mipmap.expand_4);
       imagerequestserver(docDatalist.get(position), vinappserial, holder);
    } else {
       holder.recyclerViewImages.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       holder.iconexpandCollapse.setImageResource(R.mipmap.expand);
    }
    // expandedPosition=holder.getAdapterPosition();

    holder.myDocumentListCollapse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           sendHoldertdata.setExpandedPosition(position);
        }
    });
}

public interface SendHoldertdata {
    void setdata(ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArrayList, int count);

    void setExpandedPosition(int expandedPosition);
}
```

And on your `activity/fragment` (Its just what you are going to the passed `expandedPosition`):

```
private int expandedPosition = -1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
   ...more code
   NewAdpater newAdpater = new NewAdpater(docDataList, context, vinappserial, new SendHoldertdata() {
       @Override
       public void setdata(ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArrayList, int count) {
          ...your code
       }

       @Override
       public void setExpandedPosition(int expandedPosition) {
          YourActivityName.this.expandedPosition = expandedPosition;
          newAdpater.notifyDataSetChanged(); //call this to refresh the state, so it will call the onBindViewHolder again on the adapter.
       }
   }, expandedPosition);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tenten let me check this

Comment: does not work, We cannot override method inside onCreate()

Comment: Please share  your activity code or where your accessing the adapter.

Comment: Please check the updated one. I post the code of the activity

Comment: It seems that you've implemented it successfully on your activity, have you also updated there your `NewAdpater` class to my answer?

Comment: Yes, But all the time position goes - 1 in the adapter

Comment: If you click, the expandedPosition must update. Can you put a `Log.d` (just to make sure the method is getting called upon clicking) on the `public void setExpandedPosition(int expandedPosition)`?

Comment: I am not using an expandable listview. I am not getting the data from the API in that manner.

Comment: No, you don't need expandable listview here, I just want you to log if the expandedPosition on your activity is changing once you click on your `myDocumentListCollapse`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it. According to this [Expendable-Recycler-View](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view) you can add below code in your **parentViewHolder**. `mArrowExpandImageView` is the imageView I used to show expand/collapse icon and on it's click I did all the working. You can do something similar to get your required result. Do take a look at **ExpendableRecyclerAdapter** class in the library for the working of expand and collapse.

```
  @Override
public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
    super.setExpanded(expanded);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        if (expanded) {
            mArrowExpandImageView.setRotation(ROTATED_POSITION);
        } else {
            mArrowExpandImageView.setRotation(INITIAL_POSITION);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onExpansionToggled(boolean expanded) {
    super.onExpansionToggled(expanded);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        RotateAnimation rotateAnimation;
        if (expanded) { // rotate clockwise
            rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(ROTATED_POSITION,
                    INITIAL_POSITION,
                    RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                    RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        } else { // rotate counterclockwise
            rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(-1 * ROTATED_POSITION,
                    INITIAL_POSITION,
                    RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                    RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        }

        rotateAnimation.setDuration(200);
        rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        mArrowExpandImageView.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
    }
}
```

and then in your fragment/activity you need to implement the expand collapse listener like this:

```
                yourAdapter.setExpandCollapseListener(new ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.ExpandCollapseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onListItemExpanded(int position) {

                    expendedItemPosition = position;
                    yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onListItemCollapsed(int position) {

                    expendedItemPosition = -1;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Umair I am unable to use ExpandableListview

Comment: @Champandorid i told you dear that I used this using the library so these methods are from the library that's why they are overridden. I just wanted to gave you the idea how to use it. If you want to use the library just add this in your gradle file and you can use above code as it is.

 compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:2.1.1'

Comment: or you will have to implement expendable listview then :)

Comment: @Champandorid it seems that the logic of my answer is the same on the library sir Umair is using. (Well this is cooler because it has some animations)